# how internally doPost method in servlet works

Tags: java

Why query string is not getting created in doPost method of HttpServlet?
Is this reason is enough - it is supplying data in html body.
can anyone please clarify what actually happening

Comment: Did you google before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get and post methods are almost the same, the only difference between these two methods is that: in post, query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request and in get, query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL.

Why is this done this way, obviously, security reasons.

You do not want to see your login credentials in the url.